# What will happen if I changed the file read/write permission while others doing reading/writing?

Tags: linux, filesystems

What will happen if:

scenario 1:

1、others open fileA(with 644 permission) for reading

2、I do `chmod 600 fileA` while he's still reading the file

scenario 2:

1、others open fileA(with 644 permission) to write something

2、I do `chmod 600 fileA` while he's still writing to file

Will the read/write operation failed in the middle of the progress?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/631766/can-i-get-unix-file-permissions-to-take-effect-immediately-for-all-processes

Comment: chatGpt has given amazing answer for this.